# Python - openpyxl search for string - object not callable

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to python and reached a bit of a stumbling block. I'm trying to search an excel sheet column for a specified value so that I can perform more operations on that row. I've tried a few different examples I've found online but cannot seem to get it working.

`TypeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object is not callable`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl


def search_for_part(stock_id):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename="1.xlsx", read_only=True)
    sheet = workbook.active
    for row in sheet("A"):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == stock_id:
                print(sheet.cell)
    

v1 = "VEM004"
search_for_part(v1)
```

I thought the `("A")` in `for row in sheet("A"):` was for searching in column A only, but removing it gives the following output which makes me think I'm closer.

`<bound method Worksheet.cell of <openpyxl.worksheet._read_only.ReadOnlyWorksheet object at 0x00000197A8314A48>>`

Comment: Do you *need* to use openpyxl? Could you use pandas to `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: @jasonm  openpyxl was just the first excel library I came across. I will take a look at pandas. I have got the writing to excel sheets figured out with openpyxl just not reading values yet.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: @AMC - My initial thoughts were that it was displaying a type error because I was looking for a string rather than an integer, but I tried changing my variable to int and get the same error.

 I think it could be to do with `for row in sheet("A"):` I thought `("A")` was to read only column A, but removing A gives me a running program but not the desired output of a cell. It produces this instead.. `<bound method Worksheet.cell of <openpyxl.worksheet._read_only.ReadOnlyWorksheet object at 0x00000197A8314A48>>`

Comment: _I thought ("A") was to read only column A_ What do the docs say?

Comment: @AMC Thank you. I have got it working with a gentle push from yourself and bit of help from the other answer I have created my own. It may not be perfect or the shortest way to the problem but it is working

Comment: @Zak I'm glad you figured things out. Did you ever find how to access a column?

Answer (score 1):

`sheet` is a worksheet, so when you say `sheet(anything)` you're trying to "call" it.  And worksheets are not (as the message indicates) callable.

What you probably want is something like

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if row[0] == stock_id:
        print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of perseverance and help from AMC and Chris. I have come up with the following which gives me the desired output.

```
def search_for_part(stock_id):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename="1.xlsx", read_only=True)
    sheet = workbook.active
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == stock_id:
                col_a = row[0]
                col_b = row[1]
                col_c = row[2]
                return col_a.value, col_b.value, col_c.value
```